# How to convert iOS Swift app form version 2 to version 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I want to convert an app which is written in Swift2 to Swift4 or Swift3. I know I can convert it using Xcode8 but the problem is I updated my mac to macOS mojave and when I try to open Xcode 8.3.3 it crashes all the time and I cannot go back to HighSeria because I have many on going projects right now so don't want to take risk. Any solution to convert Swift2 app to Swift3 or Swift4?

Comment: There isn't an automated option without using earlier versions of Xcode. You can just do it manually.

Comment: @Paulw11 I can't because it's an old project and some other developer do it so I didn't know what he used in the app and what I have to change

Comment: Don't you have an external hard disk? Partition it and install an Xcode 8 compatible macOS version.

Comment: @EmmJay you can. You just need to load the project in Xcode 10, change the Swift version in the project settings and then edit the code to Swift 4.  It isn't as easy as the automated approach but it is possible. Xcode will flag lines with errors and even suggest fixes if it detects obsolete code.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. Sad!!!!!